# Text direction (right to left) in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, text, openpyxl, direction

I'd like to write Arabic text in a cell Each text is preceded by number
when I run the code, the number appeared after text that due to
the default text direction is left to right.
could change text direction to be right to leftin certain cells?

[image]

change text direction to be right to left in certain cells

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean `text direction` or `text alignment`?

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome he means text direction

Comment: With Arabic characters the direction should automatically change to right to left. Reversing text is easy enough but with Arabic characters it may not work out as you expect for the reason in the first sentence .

Answer (score 1):

Openpyxl implements the OOXML specification. It looks like the `Alignment.readingOrder` attribute is relevant here. This is defined as:

````
0 - Context Dependent - reading order is determined by scanning the text for the first non-whitespace character: if it is a strong right-to-left character, the reading order is right-to-left; otherwise, the reading order left-to-right.
1 - Left-to-Right- reading order is left-to-right in the cell, as in English.
2 - Right-to-Left - reading order is right-to-left in the cell, as in Hebrew.
The possible values for this attribute are defined by the W3C XML Schema unsignedInt datatype.```
````